# Is the MSDN documentation for DataContractSerializer incorrect?

Tags: c#, msdn, datacontractserializer

The [MSDN documentation for DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732(v=vs.110).aspx) contains the following statement:

> Read-only fields, properties without a get or set method, and properties with internal or private set or get methods are not serialized. Such properties are ignored and no exception is thrown, except in the case of get-only collections.

However, I just created the following program which serializes readonly, get-only, and private-set properties just fine. Am I misunderstanding something, or is the documentation incorrect?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string saveFile = "save.xml";
            Foo originalFoo = new Foo();
            SaveState(originalFoo, saveFile);
            Foo restoredFoo = LoadState<Foo>(saveFile);
        }
        public static void SaveState(Object o, string saveFile)
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(saveFile))
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, o);
        }
        public static T LoadState<T>(string loadFile)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(loadFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                T obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                return obj;
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Foo
    {
        private readonly int X;
        private int Y { get; }
        internal int Z { get; private set; }
        public Foo()
        {
            X = Y = Z = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You used the `Serializable` attribute which means `serialize everything`

Comment: That documentation page looks incomplete.  More complete documentation is found at [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923(v=vs.110).aspx) which states that supported types include *Types marked with the SerializableAttribute attribute. Many types included in the .NET Framework base class library fall into this category. The DataContractSerializer fully supports this serialization programming model that was used by .NET Framework remoting, the BinaryFormatter, and the SoapFormatter, including support for the ISerializable interface.*

Answer (score 1):

You used the [Serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute which instructs the serializer to serialize everything. From the docs:

> When you apply the SerializableAttribute attribute to a type, all private and public fields are serialized by default. You can control serialization more granularly by implementing the ISerializable interface to override the serialization process.

If you ommit all attributes, only public properties and fields are serialized, as described in the documentation. For example, if you add a `W` property:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly int X;
    private int Y { get; }
    internal int Z { get; private set; }


    public int W { get; set; }
    public Foo()
    {
        X = Y = Z = 10;
    }
}
```

The generated file will contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SO_Serializer">
    <W>15</W>
</Foo>
```

If you add the `DataContract`attribute to the class, only the members marked with `DataMember` will be serialized

Comment: The information you provided was very instructive. Thank you. However, I still maintain that the MSDN documentation is MISLEADING at best. It suggests there is no way to serialize the readonly properties, which is simply not true. It makes no mention of the `[Serializable]` attribute and leaves one to believe there is no workaround for this shortcoming.

Comment: To make matters worse, the link you provided to the [Serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation adds to the confusion because it says that classes with that attribute "cannot be inherited". And yet I had no problem creating a `Bar` class that inherited from `Foo` and both were serialized.

Comment: The docs don't say anything of the kind. They say what happens if you use the appropriate attributes. You used the generic `Serializable` attribute though, whose meaning is "serialize everything".

Comment: @kmote no, it says that the `SerializableClass` can't be inherited. It can't because it's sealed

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the SerialzableClass. My mistake. As to your previous comment, you mention "appropriate attributes". Are you saying that the use of `[Serializable]` is _not_ appropriate with the DataContractSerializer? Does that imply that it is a hack that I should avoid? If that attribute is *not supported* then your argument makes sense. But if it is, then the documentation should at least mention it, don't you think?

Comment: It does, on the chapter on serialization in general. The DataContract attributes and serializer though, belong to a different section which deals primarily with WCF and SOAP. The *attributes* actually define the data contract used by a WCF/SOAP service. They are used to create the XSDs exposed by a web or WCF service. The DataContractSerializer is "just" the serializer that understands them. By using `Serializable` instead of `DataContract` you caused a lot more problems than incorrect serialization

Answer (score 0):

No ,It's not incorrect !

Read-only fields, properties without a get or set method, and properties with internal or private set or get methods are not serialized. Such properties are ignored and no exception is thrown, except in the case of get-only collections.

> Apply the SerializableAttribute attribute even if the class also implements the ISerializable interface to control the serialization process.
>
> When you apply the SerializableAttribute attribute to a type, all private and public fields are serialized by default. You can control serialization more granularly by implementing the ISerializable interface to override the serialization process.
>
> Or you can exclude fields from serialization by applying the NonSerializedAttribute attribute to the field. If a field of a serializable type contains a pointer, a handle, or some other data structure that is specific to a particular environment, and cannot be meaningfully reconstituted in a different environment, then you might want to apply the NonSerializedAttribute attribute to that field.

Comment: I downvoted you because you say that I'm wrong even though I posted code to prove otherwise, and you provided no insight beyond a statement that I already quoted in my original post.

Comment: @kmote that's no reason to downvote, otherwise people could take issue with the fact that you use an attribute that's not intended to define data contracts, and apply it to them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, If this answer had explained that the attribute I used was not intended to define data contracts, I would not have down-voted it. As it stands, it provides literally no useful information. I would be happy to revise my downvote it if it is edited.